# NSwag - How to hide base URL , Version , Scheme from swagger UI

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nswag

I am using .NET Core WebAPI (Nswag) I wanted to hide below items from swagger UI. Is that possible?

1. 'Select Definition' and dropdown (Top right corner)
2. BaseURL and Swagger.json link
3. Schemes and dropdown.

Highlighted in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add your own custom CSS](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#inject-custom-css) and use it to hide those elements (and do any other customisation you want).

Create a `wwwroot/swagger-ui` folder in the root of your project, and add `custom.css` to it:

```
.swagger-ui .topbar .download-url-wrapper {
    display: none;
}

.swagger-ui .info hgroup.main a {
    display: none;
}

.swagger-ui section.models {
    display: none;
}
```

And in Program.cs (Startup.cs in .Net5):

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
    });
```

Don't forget `app.UseStaticFiles();`.

Result:

[image]

Is this what you want?

**Update:**

NSwag can also customize CSS styles:

custom.css:

```
.swagger-ui .topbar .download-url-wrapper {
    display : none;
}

.swagger-ui .info .base-url {
    display : none;
}

.swagger-ui .info hgroup.main a {
    display: none;
}

.swagger-ui .scheme-container {
    display : none;
}
```

And in Program.cs (Startup.cs in .Net5):

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(c => {
        c.CustomStylesheetPath = "/swagger-ui/custom.css";
    });
```

Don't forget `app.UseStaticFiles();`.

Result:
[image]

Comment: No.. I think, this uses swashbuckle. But here i am using NSwag..

Comment: Hi @Sathish, I updated my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: Thanks , it works for me. Accepting it as answer